# How to only enter a date that is a weekday in Python

Tags: python, forms, flask

I'm creating a web applcation in Python and I only want the user to be able to enter a weekday that is older than today's date. I've had a look at isoweekday() for example but don't know how to integrate it into a flask form. The form currently looks like this:

`appointment_date = DateField('Appointment Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a weekday, you should put a `select` or a `textbox`, not a `date picker`.

If you put a `select`, you can disable the days before today so you don't even need a validation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what would I need to change in the code to do this? Thanks

Comment: You can use something like this: `SelectField(u'Field name', choices = myChoices, validators = [Required()])`. Take a look at [docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)

Comment: but how would I set this so that the number of days in the month is correct? Eg not having 31 in every month?