# Python Flask DateField disable weekends

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, datefield

I was wondering if it would be possible to add in any validation to make sure that the date selected isn't a weekend? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
appointment_date = DateField('Appointment Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today(), validators=[DateRange(min=date.today()), DataRequired()])
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only enter a date that is a weekday in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258105/how-to-only-enter-a-date-that-is-a-weekday-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

In order to check something like the day of the week look into Python3's documentation where it shows something like:

```
>>> my_date = date(2002, 12, 4)
>>> my_date.isoweekday()
3
```

Where Monday is day 1 and Sunday is day 7.

source:
[date.isoweekday()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday)

Comment: I have had a look at this but do not know how to implement it into the code I provided

Answer (score 0):

Custom data validation in WTForms can easily be implemented by defining a custom validator https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#custom-validators. This is any callable that accepts 2 positional arguments, form and field, and raises  wtforms.ValidationError if the validation fails.

```
class WeekdayValidator(object):
    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if field.data and field.data.isoweekday() > 5:
            raise ValidationError("Date selected cannot be a weekend.")
```

This can then be used along with the other validators in your field definition.

```
appointment_date = DateField('Appointment Date', 
                             format='%Y-%m-%d',
                             default=date.today(), 
                             validators=[WeekdayValidator(), 
                                         DateRange(min=date.today()),
                                         DataRequired()])
```